# What Python standard library data structure would you use to store a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, spreadsheet

The sparse matrix in question is a spreadsheet, which are often quite sparsely populated.
However, they can also be fully populated, so the data structure used should not degrade too badly when that's the case.

Why the stdlib requirement? Well, 'cos I'm thinking about a library for dealing with spreadsheets in Python, and I want it to be based on the stdlib only.

Comment: You could use a dictionary and store the fields that are populated as tuples: `{(1, 2): 5}`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a list of dicts:

```
sparse = [{"ID":0, "Value1":123, "Value999":0},
          {"ID":1, "Value123":999}, # etc.
         ]
```

(You would probably want to use different keys than `Value_x`)